# HP Biometric API for .net application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, biometrics

What are the good `API` for `Biometric` `Authentication` in `.Net` and is this possible that i am using built in finger print sensor for authentication in my application
I am working on `.Net`

Comment: I think the API would be product dependent, so please state your product (biometric fingerprint device) of choice

Comment: In device manager i see this               
`Validity Sensors (WBF) (PID=0018)`
how i can use it in my application?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor http://www.validityinc.com/technology.php ? I don't think there is a generic API that fits all

Comment: Not yet contact
If i am using some other device that API for that device is free available?
My problem is that i am new in device specific API your help will me more useful or if you may guide me about some device for that purpose

Comment: I have yet to see a single API to "rule" all of the biometric devices out there